# attribute on selectonemenu jsf

Tags: css, jsf-2, liferay, custom-component, renderer

I have a little trouble with tag h:selectOneMenu, I just want to add some background image to option, such as avatar of user.

Follow [styling options in h:selectOneMenu - by balusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/08/styling-options-in-hselectonemenu.html)

I had tried to render options with its own style css.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="dropListUser"
        value="#{myController.myUserObject.userid}">
    <f:attribute name="avatar" value="#{true}"></f:attribute>                           
    <f:attribute name="key" value="somthing"></f:attribute>
    <f:attribute name="height" value="32"></f:attribute>
    <f:attribute name="width" value="32"></f:attribute>
    <f:selectItems value="#{myController.listOfUsers}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.username}" itemValue="#{item.userid}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

It work great with height, width and key, but with avatar(or any attribute contains value with #{} expression) server bean could not get it.

Try to printout all key name:

```
Iterator itr = component.getAttributes().keySet().iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr.next().toString());
        }
```

there is no key with name avatar :

```
--------------------------------
height
javax.faces.component.VIEW_LOCATION_KEY
com.sun.faces.facelets.MARK_ID
key
width
width: 32 height: 32 style null?: true
--------------------------------
```

ps: by the way,Is there any one know how to create custom taglib that extends h:selectOneMenu :-?

ps2: In the fact, If I could get `myController.listOfUsers` 
in `<f:selectItems value="#{myController.listOfUsers}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.username}" itemValue="#{item.userid}"/>` in my custom render bean, it could be better

Comment: isn't that article by BalusC is exactly what are you looking for ? he demonstrates how to extend h:selectOneMen...

Comment: yeah, but I want to pass expression such as #{myController.myProps} as f:attribute value, not static value ...,

Comment: does it works with a static value for you? cause if is does , it should work with an expression too

Comment: hmm, as I said. static value work nice, but not with expression, attribute value with expression could not be found in server. I was print out all attribute name, but it's not there

Comment: what wrong in `<f:selectItems value="#{myController.listOfUsers}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.username}" itemValue="#{item.userid}"/>`

Comment: nope, just wonder how to get `#{myController.listOfUsers}` in `public class ExtendedMenuRenderer  extends MenuRenderer{...}`

Comment: sorry for bad English skill :))

Comment: its a baaaad idea.... this kind of logic not supposed to be located in `ExtendedMenuRenderer `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woof, I don't know why or how, but when try print out all of key names from `component.getAttributes()` also `component.getAttributes().containsKey("avatar")` return that avatar is not exist, BUT I really can get avatar value, my trouble was solved ^^" just remove code that check  the key exist or not